# Finding $\sum_i^nx_iI(x_i>0)$ given limited knowledge of sequence $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I want to find $$\sum_{i=1}^nx_iI(x_i>0)$$
but given only knowledge of $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$ and $n$. Is this possible if $x$ is a real number?

Where $I(\text{[cond]})$ is indicator function returning $1$ if [cond] is true, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: The question does not make sense. What is $I$? Please clarify.

Comment: @6005  I agree the question is phrased poorly. I interpret $I$ to be an indicator, or characteristic, function.  Thus $I(x_i>0)=1$ if $x_i>0$ and $0$ otherwise.  Perhaps the OP can confirm?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the indicator function.

Comment: May I suggest: edit the question for clarity?  You're new to the site (welcome!), and it's worth pointing out that one of the goals here is to have good,clear questions and answers that people can consult in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question for you so don't worry about editing it further. It should give you some good idea of what a clear question looks like. Mostly you did well, just make sure to define everything and repeat your question in your post (instead of having some of the important info only in the title.)

Comment: @6005 thank you, I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Let $S=\sum x_i$ and write it as $S=S_+ + S_-$ where $S_+$ is the desired sum over the terms $>0$ and $S_-$ is the sum over the terms $<0$.

Then $P=\sum |x_i|=S_+ - S_-$ So $$S_+=\frac 12\times \left(S+P\right)$$

Note:  we don't need to know $n$.